# Mobile chat chops off the numbers

Tags: bug, design, chat, mobile-web

As seen in the image below, the numbers (which represent seconds left for a timeout to end) are chopped off.

They start as a whole from the bottom left corner, but are chopped off on the way, first at a higher speed, and then slowly such that at the end, only the `o` of `6` or `8` remains visible.

[image]

Comment: Also repro-ed on Chrome.